# mat-slider not recognised despite being imported

Tags: angular

app.module.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
// import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; // CLI imports AppRoutingModule


import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatSliderModule } from '@angular/material/slider';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HighchartsChartModule } from 'highcharts-angular';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatSliderModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        FormsModule,
        HighchartsChartModule,
        NgbModule,
        HttpClientModule
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule { }
```

my-component.component.html:

```
<mat-card-content style="word-wrap: break-word; ">
    <mat-slider class="example">
    </mat-slider>
</mat-card-content>
```

my-component.component.ts

```
imports ...
@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
    styleUrls: [
        '../../../app.component.css',
        "./my-component.component.css",
        "../../../../../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css",
    ],
})
```

error:
`error NG8001: 'mat-slider' is not a known element: 1. If 'mat-slider' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.`

Afaik I'm importing correct stuff, even though its imported to my entire app.module.ts and not just my component. What am I missing?

Comment: is my-component selector points to AppComponent declared in root module or not? If it points to another component then be sure to declare this component in the module above.

Comment: If you cannot compile despite the component being correctly declared, then close your editor and open it again it should recognize your import

Comment: thanks @Walid, the problem was because I incorrectly pointed modules.

Answer (score 0):

Is `my-component` selector points to `AppComponent` declared in `root module` or not? If it points to another `component`, then be sure to declare this `component` in the respective `module` with correct `MatModules` imports. Otherwise, add the declaration in the `module` above.